# Unreal Won't Launch To Oculus Quest 2 Without Restart

Tags: unreal-engine4, oculus

I'm using Unreal 4.26.0 and I finally got it to launch to my Oculus Quest 2.  However, it doesn't always launch the latest version.

So, I might make a change, build the project, then launch the app on the Quest via Launch => Quest 2.

Eventually, it starts running on the headset, but often it doesn't have the latest changes.  If I shutdown Unreal, then restart it, it does get the latest version.

How do I consistently have it launch the latest version of the app?  Is there some formula for getting it to properly copy over during launch? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I did find the solution... just in case someone else has this same problem:

I did not have all the environment variables set correctly for Android/Java.  I had to make sure all these were set:

```
JAVA_HOME
ANDROID_HOME
ANDROID_TOOLS
ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS
ANDROID_NDK_HOME
```

So, after making sure each of those were specified, I also had to put each into my $PATH.

I should also note that I'm using Unreal 4.26, Android SDK 10, and Android NDK 22.0.7026061.  These aren't exactly what the directions call for, but the directions are a bit old.  These are (mostly) the newest versions as of this writing.

Comment: Did this work for anyone else?  Would be nice to know some context (or see some upvotes) before devoting ~20 minutes to trying things this way